# Why can't we omit parentheses from array destruction in array function parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Lets say I have the following codes:

1. This example works

   ```
   ...
   .filter(([,second]) => console.log(second))
   ```
2. This does not

   ```
   ...
   .filter([,second] => console.log(second))
   ```

Why do we have to wrap array destruction into parentheses? Isn't it boilerplate?

Comment: Arrow functions are defined like this in ES6 and later specs, so it's not necessarily a typescript-related issue. I agree though, I don't see a good reason for why there needs to be parentheses around arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the what the `ES2015` spec states the behavior should be. The `()` are only optional if the parameter list is just a single simple parameter.

From the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers)

> ```
> ArrowFunction[In, Yield] :
>      ArrowParameters[?Yield] [no LineTerminator here] => ConciseBody[?In]
> ArrowParameters[Yield] :
>      BindingIdentifier[?Yield]
>      CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList
> ```

So the arrow parameters can be either a binding identifier or a `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList`

The `CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList` is a regular parameter list (as seen [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-primary-expression))

> ```
> CoverParenthesizedExpressionAndArrowParameterList[Yield] :
>      ( Expression[In, ?Yield] )
>      ( )
>      ( ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] )
>      ( Expression[In, ?Yield] , ... BindingIdentifier[?Yield] )
> ```

So the case when we can write a simple parameter is the `BindingIdentifier` case, which as seen [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers) is just a simple identifier, so you can't use a de-structuring pattern:

> ```
> BindingIdentifier[Yield] :Identifier
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think it is something which worth modification request in the upcoming spec?

Comment: @BalázsTakács don't know